# AWS S3: File not uploading when in function

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using this [AWS S3 PHP Library](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) to upload a file to my AWS Bucket. The code used is:

```
if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile('file.json'), $bucket, 'file.json', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
    echo "File uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Failed to upload file.";
}
```

If I just add this statement into the general scope of the document it works fine. however when I add it into a function like so:

```
function updateFileToS3() {
     if (S3::putObject(S3::inputFile('file.json'), $bucket, 'file.json', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
    echo "File uploaded.";
    } else {
    echo "Failed to upload file.";
    }
 }
```

and call it further down the page:

```
updateFileToS3();
```

I get the result

> Failed to upload file.

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: I chose this SDK because its very small compared to the massive one that amazon produces, and I'm only going to be using it to upload files. Also, the amazon one is quite confusing, whereas there was a tutorial with this one.

Comment: a full well mannered document is there http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/ for AWS PHP

Comment: Please,could you specify where and how you define `$bucket` variable?

Comment: $bucket  is defined at the top with all other variables..

Comment: could you catch the error and display the error message instead of "Failed to upload"?